# How to display sql query nested xml in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, gridview

So, I have xml configuration file in asp.net with nested sql queries to display data in GridView. I have never seen xml code in this format, any ideas?

```
<grid>
<primary_key>DeclarationGUID</primary_key>
<query>
    SELECT DeclarationGUID,
        SequenceNum,
        AcceptanceDate,
    FROM Declaration
</query>
<grid>
    <foreign_key>DeclarationGUID</foreign_key>
    <primary_key>GoodsItemGUID</primary_key>
    <query>
        SELECT DeclarationGUID,
            GoodsItemGUID,
            SequenceNum,
            CommodityCode,
        FROM GoodsItem 
        WHERE DeclarationGUID=@@DeclarationGUID@@
    </query>
    <grid>
        <foreign_key>DeclarationGUID</foreign_key>
        <foreign_key>GoodsItemGUID</foreign_key>
        <primary_key>ContainerGUID</primary_key>
        <query>
            SELECT DeclarationGUID,
                GoodsItemGUID,
                ContainerGUID,
                Identifier
            FROM GoodsItemContainer
            WHERE GoodsItemGUID=@@GoodsItemGUID@@
        </query>
    </grid>
</grid>
```

Comment: Maybe mock up what you want the grid to look like? Grids are generally not great hierarchical data.

Comment: grid row has function to expand to show lower hierarchy data. my problem is sql query code in xml config file

Comment: You mean you need to run those queries and show the data that they return? That was not clear to me, and probably more involved than a single forum question.

Comment: As @Crowcoder says, you probably need to parse the XML, execute the queries and show the results. However it seems to me that whoever made the XML would also have made a custom method for processing it, otherwise it would not make much sense.

Comment: the main thing that i don't understand is that whole changing process should be run-time, so you can't compile code every time. so i will have this XML configuration file, where i will change SQL queries in real time then parse it and execute with Ado.net? what the purpose of putting SQL query in XML code if i have to parse it from there ? makes no sense

Comment: The xml looks like a log file that was made while running queries on the database.  Are you really converting SQL database to Access (Ado.Net)?

Comment: first of all this XML file can be updated manually so i want to always get latest queries, then i am executing query and getting DataTable. So i will have 3 datatables and i want to display them as hierarchy